# Securing an API with a Token

Tags: api, security, asp.net-web-api, cryptography, token

I'm currently in the process of developing an API but I am slightly stumped on how I'd go about securing it. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I'm not an expert on cryptography.

My current plan would be as follows;

- Check if the client is communicating over HTTPS
- Check if the client has a token, if they do then validate it otherwise get them to login (return a 401)

To validate the token I would check if it exists in the database and if it does check it hasn't expired.

If the token doesn't exist, I would ask them to authenticate. This would involve sending their username and password to the server over HTTPS, I would check it using a traditional approach (hash it, salt it, compare it etc.) If it all checks out, then I'd create a session key/token/random string and in all future requests ask them to send it with their API request.

Does this sound like a sensible approach?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds good. If you issue a digitally signed token, then there's no need to do a database lookup.

Comment: It really sounds like you are trying to re-invent the wheel, and for this topic can be dangerous - depending on what version of ASP.NET (e.g. OWIN) you can use established methods for issuing and validating tokens based on your scenario.  You're talking about Authorization (OAuth) while also talking about proper password storage.  For example see: [link](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/).  There's tons of articles out there of using tokens, and proper password storage in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to use single sign on and delegate the token generation to a Security Token Service, like [Thinktecture's Identity Server](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/).
Then on the API side, you will just have to configure Bearer token authentication, something like this:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:44319/identity",
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "sampleApi" }
    });
```

complete example here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds ok to me for starters. What you are thinking of is Basic Authentication followed by Token based Authorization. But you should also consider having some kind of obfuscation technique for sending username and password. Like base64 it in a specific format that only your algorithm can decrypt on the server side. Here is a good tutorial that should help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005485/RESTful-Day-sharp-Security-in-Web-APIs-Basic

Comment: You should use basic authentication only in combination with HTTPS, so there's no need for obfuscation. Also, base64 is an encoding, not encryption.

Comment: @MvdD I suggested that as an extra measure and in a hurry I used the term "decrypt" as opposed to "decode". Besides that I did not suggest anything awful.